# Run jQuery function onclick with mutiple images in fotorama

Tags: jquery, image, hyperlink, onclick, fotorama

I am using the fotorama script for an image gallery. It took me a little bit of time to figure out the correct syntax for modifying the script so that the rotating image was clickable. (see the JS in the code below) What I'm looking to do is have each rotating image click to a different URL.  For example, in the code below, image "/03.jpg" could like to "google.com", link "/04.jpg" could link to "yahoo.com", and image "/05.jpg" could link to "bing.com".

```
<div id="fotorama">
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/03.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/03.jpg" alt="Masha">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/04.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/04.jpg" alt="Sasha">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/05.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/05.jpg" alt="Klava">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/06.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/06.jpg" alt="Dunya">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/07.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/07.jpg" alt="Svetlana Nikolaevna">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/08.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/08.jpg" alt="Zhenechka">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/01.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/01.jpg" alt="Potapova Yulya">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/09.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/09.jpg" alt="Asel">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/10.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/10.jpg" alt="Ekaterina">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/11.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/11.jpg" alt="Varya">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/12.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/12.jpg" alt="Marina Petrova">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/13.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/13.jpg" alt="Frosya">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/14.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/14.jpg" alt="Sonechka">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/15.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/15.jpg" alt="Galina">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/16.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/16.jpg" alt="Tatiana">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/17.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/17.jpg" alt="Artemida">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/18.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/18.jpg" alt="Sofia">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/19.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/19.jpg" alt="Nina">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/20.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/20.jpg" alt="Valentina">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/21.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/21.jpg" alt="Kristina">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/02.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/02.jpg" alt="Browny">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/22.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/22.jpg" alt="Gulchitai">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/23.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/23.jpg" alt="Elena">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/24.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/24.jpg" alt="Olga">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/25.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/25.jpg" alt="Tonya">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/26.jpg">
        <img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/26.jpg" alt="Feodora">
    </a>
</div>






// Change ↓values↓, press ↑Run↑, see →Result→
$('#fotorama').fotorama({
    width: '100%',
    height: 'auto',
    aspectRatio: 1.4989293362, // =700/467

    minWidth: null,
    maxWidth: null,
    minHeight: null,
    maxHeight: null,

    transition: 'slide', // or 'fade'
    click: true,
    loop: false, // or true

    autoplay: false,
    stopAutoplayOnAction: true,

    transitionDuration: 333,

    background: null,
    // 'black', '#b10000', or url(bg.png)
    margin: 4,
    minPadding: 8,
    alwaysPadding: false,
    zoomToFit: true,
    cropToFit: false,
    cropToFitIfFullscreen: false,

    flexible: false,
    fitToWindowHeight: false,
    fitToWindowHeightMargin: 20,

    fullscreen: false,
    fullscreenIcon: false,

    vertical: false,

    arrows: true,
    arrowsColor: null,
    arrowPrev: null,
    arrowNext: null,

    spinnerColor: '#808080',

    nav: 'thumbs', // or 'dots', or 'none'
    navPosition: 'auto',
    // 'top' | 'right' | 'bottom' || 'left'   
    navBackground: null,
    dotColor: null,
    thumbSize: null, // 36 or 51, whatever :-)
    thumbMargin: 4,
    thumbBorderWidth: 2,
    thumbBorderColor: null,
    // 'white', '#ff9', or even '#00ff84 #00eb89 #00b66f'
    thumbsCentered: true,
    hideNavIfFullscreen: false,

    caption: 'overlay', // 'simple', or 'none'

    preload: 3,
    preloader: 'dark', // or 'white'

    shadows: true,

    data: null,
    // e.g. [{img: 'http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/03.jpg'}, {img: 'broken.jpg'}, {img: 'http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/13.jpg'}]

    html: null,

    hash: false,
    startImg: 0,

    cssTransitions: true,

    onShowImg: null,
    // function(data){alert('Photo #'+(data.index+1)+' is coming!')}
    onClick: function(data){
        window.location = '/YourPage.html'
    },
    onFullscreenOpen: null,
    onFullscreenClose: null,
    onTransitionStop: null
});
```

Can someone help please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, while waiting for better solutions: (i have tested with first example)

HTML:

```
<h1>Fotorama example</h1>

<div class="fotorama" data-width="499" data-height="333" data-click="false">
    <a  href="i/01.jpg"><img src="i/thumbs/01.jpg"  ></a>
    <a  href="i/02.jpg"><img src="i/thumbs/02.jpg"  ></a>
    <a  href="i/03.jpg"><img src="i/thumbs/03.jpg"  ></a>

</div>
```

Notice data-click=false -> this option is available, and it will stop 'Moving between images by clicking.'

And, now hack:

JQuery

```
$(window).load(function() {

links=new Array('http://www.google.com','http://www.yahoo.com','http://www.facebook.com' );


     jQuery.each($(".fotorama img"), function(i) {

$(this).attr('title',links[i]);


});

$(".fotorama img").click(function() {

    loc=$(this).attr('title');
    //alert(loc);

    window.location=loc;

});


});
```

This will work, but i would like to see better solution too. @Gökhan Girgin - yes, very weird, obfuscated slideshow script... :)

Comment: Thanks "Nevermind"! This is huge! It is working on our end, tho it does seem to be disabling some other javascripts that are running on the page. It is a tad bit on the buggy side so I can see why the suggestion for a better solution. (Buggy meaning the images and their corresponding clickthroughs don't seem to have a consistent order, but I can work with that.)  Thanks again for all of your guys help and I will post if I find anymore info this.

Comment: A couple other things about this I was wondering if anyone could help with or explain.  First off, in Neverminds example above, links are provided. Do you think we could somehow map each "main" image as opposed to having it just go to one link?  Secondly, is there any control of the images "alt" tags rather than just showing the destination link of the image?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Buford, np. However - solution shouldn't be buggy, the rest of the scripts should work fine, as long as there are no variable namings collision, or something like that... Problem with this (fotorama) script - it is obfuscated (intentionally, i would say), and it is hard to change it -> also, if you save your test file, you will notice strange html source (output from script) - it places thumbs in canvas tag - they can't be saved (?) (try it), so, only big images are present in html source after page saving... though stuff, for sure... :)

Comment: Hmm Thanks for the heads up Nevermind, I'll have to check it out.  For anyone else that may experience a challenge with scripts (as I mentioned above), my problem was that i had two instances of jquery running, only one needed.

Comment: It's working good now :)  I figured out the script challenge (mentioned above), that was pretty much the issue.  The only other question(s) were regarding the alt tags for the images (as opposed to showing the destination url) and if it would be possible to map the image (each rotating image would have a different map) rather that a single destination url. @Nevermind you have been a huge help, thanks again.  I am also open to other rotating banner scripts that achieve this same effect without the "obfuscation" of fotorama. :)

Comment: This won't work for mobile devices as the click event is not triggered unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at first **data-href**

```
<img src="http://fotoramajs.com/;-)/th/03.jpg" data-href="http://example.com" alt="Masha">
```

and add the script to your page

```
$(document).on("click","img",function(){

var url = $(this).data("href");
if(url != undefined && url != null)
{
   $(location).attr("href",url);
}

});
```

Comment: This will not work. Fotorama creates specific output, image links here are links to thumbs, actually, and any attribute you set is not available on page load...

Comment: I don't know anything about the plugin but why an extra attribute breaks the plugin? too weird.

Comment: Indeed really wierd @GökhanGirgin :D

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old question but I found a better solution in the github project issues.

Taken from artpolikarpov:

This is how you wrap images with links:

```
<div class="fotorama">
    <div data-img="1.jpg"><a href="http://google.com/"></a>
    </div>
    <div data-img="2.jpg"><a href="http://yandex.ru/"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then you have to do this modification in CSS to make it work properly in IE:

```
.fotorama__html div,
.fotorama__html a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    /* Transparent links are not clickable in IE,
       but non-existent background fixes this.
      (Put an empty 1×1 image here to avoid
       errors in console.) */
    background: url(_.gif);
}
```

Taken from [here!](https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/issues/328)